# Ms-Access how to use a query with a parameter inside a form

Tags: sql, ms-access, parameters, vba

I have an SQL query with a question(alert like) that pops up every time I open it...

For every value inserted in that question you get diffrent result.

I Want to be able to use that query in my form with a combo-box...

I don't know how to exceute the query with the parameter from within the form....

I have no problem using VBA, just tell me how to call the query with the parameter

Thanks,
Fingerman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use my filtering forms using the following principles:

1) I first create a query that includes all the fields I want to display and all the fields I want to filter on. It can use more than one table. I do not set any criteria (WHERE clause) in this query unless there is a condition that always needs to be applied no matter what.

2) Next I create a datasheet form based on this query and I save it, giving it a name that indicates that it's a subform.

3) Next I create an unbound main form and add unbound controls such as textboxes, combos, listboxes, checkboxes, etc. that will be used to filter the different fields. One control can potentially allow a user to search on more than one field depending how you write your filtering routine in VBA.

4) Now it's time to write code on the main form to make this all work. Basically, the code needs to check to see if there are values in any of the controls and if so, it creates a WHERE clause (without the WHERE keyword) and at the very end it sets the subform's filter property and turns the subform's FilterOn property to TRUE.

Here's some example code. This was taken from the sample database I've made just to demonstrate filtering (see below). This example does not use fuzzy searches (asterisks) and each control on the main form only filters one field on the subform.

```
Private Sub cmdFilter_Click()
    'You can also call the FilterSubForm function on a control's AfterUpdate event.
    Call FilterSubform
End Sub

Private Sub FilterSubform()

    Dim strFilter As String

    'Note: We have to wrap field names in brackets if they contain spaces or
    'special characters. These fields are in Northwind Traders 2007 from Microsoft
    'I would never consider naming my fields with spaces or special characters
    'in them.

    'Company
    If Nz(Me.txtCompany, "") <> "" Then
        strFilter = strFilter & "Company = '" & PQ(Me.txtCompany) & "' And "
    End If
    'First Name
    If Nz(Me.txtFirstName, "") <> "" Then
        strFilter = strFilter & "[First Name] = '" & PQ(Me.txtFirstName) & "' AND "
    End If
    'Last Name
    If Nz(Me.txtLastName, "") <> "" Then
        strFilter = strFilter & "[Last Name] = '" & PQ(Me.txtLastName) & "' AND "
    End If
    'Business Phone
    If Nz(Me.txtBusinessPhone, "") <> "" Then
        strFilter = strFilter & "[Business Phone] = '" & PQ(Me.txtBusinessPhone) & "' AND "
    End If
    'City
    If Nz(Me.cboCity, "") <> "" Then
        strFilter = strFilter & "City = '" & PQ(Me.cboCity) & "' AND "
    End If
    'State/Province
    If Nz(Me.cboStateProvince, "") <> "" Then
        strFilter = strFilter & "[State/Province] = '" & PQ(Me.cboStateProvince) & "' AND "
    End If
    'Order Date
    If Nz(Me.txtOrderDate, "") <> "" Then
        If IsDate(Me.txtOrderDate) = True Then
            strFilter = strFilter & "[Order Date] = #" & Me.txtOrderDate & "# AND "
        End If
    End If
    'Ship Name
    If Nz(Me.txtShipName, "") <> "" Then
        strFilter = strFilter & "[Ship Name] = '" & PQ(Me.txtShipName) & "' AND "
    End If
    'Ship City
    If Nz(Me.txtShipCity, "") <> "" Then
        strFilter = strFilter & "[Ship City] = '" & PQ(Me.txtShipCity) & "' AND "
    End If
    'Ship State/Province
    If Nz(Me.cboShipStateProvince, "") <> "" Then
        strFilter = strFilter & "[Ship State/Province] = '" & PQ(Me.cboShipStateProvince) & "' AND "
    End If
    'Product Code
    If Nz(Me.cboProductCode, "") <> "" Then
        strFilter = strFilter & "[Product Code] = '" & PQ(Me.cboProductCode) & "' AND "
    End If
    'Quantity
    If Nz(Me.txtQuantity, "") <> "" Then
        If IsNumeric(Me.txtQuantity) = True Then
            strFilter = strFilter & "Quantity = " & Me.txtQuantity & " AND "
        End If
    End If

    If Right(strFilter, 5) = " AND " Then strFilter = Left(strFilter, Len(strFilter) - 5)

    If strFilter <> "" Then
        Me.subformOrderSearch.Form.Filter = strFilter
        Me.subformOrderSearch.Form.FilterOn = True
    Else
                   'Clear the filter
        Me.subformOrderSearch.Form.Filter = ""
        Me.subformOrderSearch.Form.FilterOn = False
    End If

End Sub

Private Function PQ(s As String) As String
    'This function is used to "pad quotes" for SQL  
        PQ = Replace(s, "'", "''")
End Function
```

I've put together a sample database that has several different examples all building on what I've posted here. You can download this database here:
http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/Search-filtering-Examples-t1968063.html

Comment: That's A nice answer.. I hoped there would be an easier solution - But this is passable. Voted as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

After some Searching, I have came across this:
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/msoffice/run-a-parameter-query-within-an-access-form/701

It is not what I wanted, But it is a great solution...

I will wait, if no one gets a better answer, I'll accept my own (As much as I hate doing that).